# ng-repeat in <script>

Tags: angularjs

here is my code. `ng-repeat` has no effect inside script for some reason. console output just has three `{{item}}` strings. I expected the letters 'a', 'b', and 'c'. why is that?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="controller">
  <script type="text/javascript" ng-repeat="item in items">
    var v = '{{item}}';
    console.log(v);
  </script>
</div>
```

​

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kuyU/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[By design, AngularJS does not template inside of `<script>` tags.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/9d-rhMiXDmg) This makes reasonable enough sense, since it is meant for generating *HTML,* not JavaScript.